# Watched/Ignored tags bug: hint for tags don't disappear

Tags: bug, ignored-tags, tag-watching

I'm talking about *Watched Tags* and *Ignored Tags* windows on the middle right of [StackOverflow's home page](https://stackoverflow.com). When you want to add another tag to your *Watched/Ignored Tags* you press *Edit* and start typing name of the tag. After you typed several characters a hint with proposed tags appears showing you names of the tags and numbers of questions for each of them: [image: tips example]

The **bug itself** is that you can stop adding a new tag and form for typing your tag together with *Add* button will disappear **BUT the hint with proposed tags will still remain on the page**: [image: bug's example]

After that you can still browse the page without any troubles but the hint-thing is still on the screen and it remains active just **as you are still typing a tag**. The only way to get rid of that glitched hint-thing is to select any of proposed tags from this list (nothing happens if you do so.. I mean, except for what you did it for).

**How to reproduce the bug**:

1. Go to [Stackoverflow's home page](https://stackoverflow.com)
2. Press *edit* button to add a tag to your *Watched/Ignored Tags*
3. Type anything in the appeared window so the hint-thing with proposed tags appears
4. After that left mouse button click anywhere on the area for text input (inside of red square on screenshot below) and **keep the mouse button pressed on**
   [image: text input]
5. And the last step is to move your cursor **out** of *Watched/Ignored Tags* window (outside of red square on screenshot below) **with left mouse button still pressed on** and release the button [image: Watched tags window]

After these steps the bug should be reproduced. I think that **this behaviour is abnormal** because it only takes some page's space, interferes you with watching other content and has no useful meaning.

This behaviour applies for both *Watched Tags* and *Ignored Tags* windows. Bug was checked with **Chrome** and **Opera**. And it was also checked on [Meta's homepage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) where it worked.

**P.s.** I searched for similar bug report on *Meta* but didn't find anything. So if it appears that the same question exists already then just close this one and I'm sorry for wasting your time. Also english is not my native language but I hope that my english skills are sufficient for you to understand what I wanted to say

Comment: Tried to reproduce following your steps, but it didn't work (using Firefox 67)

Comment: It is difficult to understand the issue without freehand circles.

Comment: I can reproduce this bug on Chrome by following your instructions, but I do have to ask: just how did you discover this? Are you perhaps using some accessibility tool that makes your mouse buttons stay pressed down until you press them again or something? (I'm asking because, if so, it would be useful to know that such a tool exists.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm not using such tool, I discovered it manually: I wanted to select all text that I typed to remove it and I selected it with mouse. But accidentally I went out of Watched Tags window's range.