# Merge [tag-watching] and [watched-tags]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, meta

I suggest merging these two Meta tags. [watched-tags](/questions/tagged/watched-tags) has less questions and no tag wiki, so I suggest to merge it into [tag-watching](/questions/tagged/tag-watching).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with this. There were just two questions that had the [watched-tags](/questions/tagged/watched-tags) tag.

- [Watched/Ignored tags bug: hint for tags don't disappear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385381/watched-ignored-tags-bug-hint-for-tags-dont-disappear)
- [Suggestions appearing only once for the same text in watched tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385744/suggestions-appearing-only-once-for-the-same-text-in-watched-tags)

and the tag didn't have a tag wiki or an excerpt. So I merged the two tags. Given that the actual name on the right hand side is "Watched Tags", I added [watched-tags](/questions/tagged/watched-tags) as a synonym for [tag-watching](/questions/tagged/tag-watching) as well, that is: [tag-watching](/questions/tagged/tag-watching) (× 14) ← [watched-tags](/questions/tagged/watched-tags) (x 2)